# Incorrect path to .jar file

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, path, sikuli

I'm using SikuliX in NetBeans to create a test. I added the dependency to my .pom file. When I try to run my test, I get the following error:

```
[error] RunTimeINIT: addToClasspath: does not exist - not added:
C:\Users\Jesper\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ElDiablo\Diablo2d\application\file:\C:\Users\Jesper\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ElDiablo\Diablo2d\application\target\diablo2d\diablo2d\modules\ext\com.se.sem4.group2.Core\com-sikulix\sikulixapi.jar!
*** classpath dump 
0: /C:/Users/Jesper/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ElDiablo/Diablo2d/application/target/surefire/surefirebooter2216122235168821312.jar
*** classpath dump end
[error] RunTimeINIT:  *** terminating: libs to export not found on above classpath: /sikulixlibs/windows/libs64
```

As you can see, the path to the .jar file is all wrong. If the first `"C:\Users\Jesper\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ElDiablo\Diablo2d\application\"` had been cut off, the path would be correct.

My question is why the first part of the path has been duplicated, and how do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same error in Eclipse / Gradle. 
The workaround in Gradle is to add a new dependency

```
 compile group: 'com.sikulix', name: 'sikulixlibswin', version: '1.1.0'
```

The workaround for this is described here https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1410072/comments/3